# Why does this Unicode / UTF-8 "En Dash" character in my JSON feed get mangled when I download it?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, httparty

My JSON feed is here:

http://america.aljazeera.com/bin/ajam/api/story.json?path=/content/ajam/watch/shows/america-tonight/articles/2014/4/28/the-dark-side-oftheoilboomhumantraffickingintheheartland

It is a JSON representation of this HTML page, you can see the same En Dash character in the subtitle of the page.

http://america.aljazeera.com/watch/shows/america-tonight/articles/2014/4/28/the-dark-side-oftheoilboomhumantraffickingintheheartland.html

The En Dash is in the 2nd key (description):

```
description: "In a North Dakota town that was once dying, oil and money are flowing – and bringing big-city problems",
```

after the word "flowing".

The page has the following HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

which can be seen by requesting it via `curl -v` or `curl -I`

Downloading it in Ruby using HTTParty like so:

```
> r = HTTParty.get('http://america.aljazeera.com/bin/ajam/api/story.json?path=/content/ajam/watch/shows/america-tonight/articles/2014/4/28/the-dark-side-oftheoilboomhumantraffickingintheheartland')
> r['description']
 => "In a North Dakota town that was once dying, oil and money are flowing –\u0080\u0093 and bringing big-city problems"
```

mangles it, as seen above. After much research I realized is a representation of the hex utf-8 unicode value as seen here:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

specifically, this:

```
UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x80 0x93 (e28093)
```

This data is later fed into an iPhone app and an Android app. On the the Android app it looks like the attached [image: Android.png]. On an iPhone it looks fine - I think because only the first character is rendered and that is a regular Ascii dash, and the next two characters are skipped.

Finally, downloading it in JavaScript using AJAX does seem to handle it correctly:

```
> r = json['description'].match(/flowing (.*) and/)[1]
> "–"
> r
> "–"
> r.length
> 3
> r.toString(16)
> "–"
```

So...what is going on? What can I do to fix it? Is the fault with the server or with my code?

Comment: It's not "mangled", it's precisely how JSON works. Use a standard JSON library to manipulate it.

Comment: I see. After I download it, I do some transformations and then expose it here: http://d3e8cn1r5u4e7p.cloudfront.net/api/simple?page=6 from where the Android app downloads it. Then the android app displays it - as seen in the screenshot - not well. So does that mean the bug is in the Android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON feed you're using failed to interpret `\u2013` correctly. Instead of generating the desired UTF-8 encoded byte sequence:

```
E2 80 93
```

it generated:

```
E2 80 93 C2 80 C2 93
```

The reason why the iPhone app works fine may be that it ignores the control character `C2 80` and `C2 93`. However, Android app just render it as some special figure.

You'll need to manually clean those wrong sequence, if you don't have control of the JSON feed.

Comment: +1 confirmed feed is broken. You can try transcoding to ISO-8859-1 and then reinterpreting those bytes as UTF-8 to fix it, but it would probably be better to report to the webmaster and try to get them to sort it out.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. How did you determine the actual bytes being sent out? (or more importantly, how can I?)

Comment: @Gal get the response via wget or browser, save it to file, and use some hex editor to check the byte sequence, such as UltraEditor or vim + xxd.