# Conversion between character encoding in java

Tags: java, encoding

I cannot find out how to do the conversion below

```
String s = "HÃ¤r har du!  â\u0080\u0093 Hur vÃ¤l kan du snacka?";
t = convert(s);
// t should be "Här har du! â Hur väl kan du snacka?"
```

I cannot find how to translate s into t. Anybody knows how to do this in Java?

Comment: Use UTF-8. Seriously—why does anyone *not* use unicode these days?

Comment: This is a strange one.  The `Ã¤` characters are obviously UTF-8 bytes coerced to characters, but the `â` is correct, and I have no idea what `\u0080\u0093` are supposed to be, as they are not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, and they wouldn't even make sense in the windows-1252 charset.  In summary, this string doesn't seem to be derived from any one charset.

Comment: You're right that the string looks very strange...

Comment: After further research, it seems to be intended to be an [EN dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)-- see [someone else's similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532778/why-does-this-unicode-utf-8-en-dash-character-in-my-json-feed-get-mangled-wh)

Comment: this basically looks like an _already corrupted_ string value.  your problem lies _before_ you got the String `s`.  wile you may be able to patch things together after the fact, fixing your actual cause is the correct solution.  where are you getting this string from in the first place?

Comment: @errantlinguist Excellent deduction.  You're correct, the string is most likely supposed to be `Här har du! – Hur väl kan du snacka?` despite the OP's claim that the 'â' should be preserved.  Which means the entire string is in fact UTF-8 bytes, each coerced to a character.  Which means Semih Eker's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sthg like this;

```
     String s = "HÃ¤r har du!  â\u0080\u0093 Hur vÃ¤l kan du snacka?";        
     byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
     String str  = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Output is ;

```
    Här har du!  – Hur väl kan du snacka?
```

For below code;

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
     String s = "HÃ¤r har du!  â\u0080\u0093 Hur vÃ¤l kan du snacka?";        
     byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
     String str  = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
     System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Your first two lines of code convert the string to bytes using UTF-8 and then back to a String using UTF-8, which means they are useless and can be removed.  Your final line, `new String(latin1)`, will use your platform's default charset, which is a very bad idea.  It *happened to work* for you, but it's hardly reliable.

Comment: That looks correct, although it's better to use StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 and StandardCharsets.UTF_8 instead of String literals, both because Strings are subject to typos and because using standard charsets removes the need to catch an exception.

Comment: Thx very much! This answered my question. The code is executed on an app server. It works perfectly, but I'll see if I can set the default encoding in the app server configuration, because of your warning.

Answer (score 1):

As i already mentioned in my comment, it looks like your String `s` is *already corrupted*.  the correct solution is to fix wherever you got `s` from in the first place.  it seems like you are interpreting what is really a "UTF-8" encoded String using some single byte encoding ("ISO8859-1" seems to work on your test string).

Provided you haven't already *lost* data in the original string corruption, you can somewhat patch your current string using:

```
    String s = "HÃ¤r har du!  â\u0080\u0093 Hur vÃ¤l kan du snacka?";        
    byte[] b = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    String t = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```